# Tracking changes for field using CDC or T-SQL with CDC

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014, unpivot, change-data-capture

Folowing CDC results set for update operation. Only `area` field has been updated.
[image]

On previous sreenshot only part of gields that contains in table. Fields are much more. Time to time some from them updates some not. In following query i try to show statistic of changes by fields in usable view.

```
with History AS (
SELECT
cz.GUID as Id, 
cz.category,
isnull(cz.area, 0) as area, 
isnull(cz.oilwidthmin,0) as oilwidthmin, 
isnull(cz.oilwidthmax,0) as oilwidthmax, 
isnull(cz.efectivwidthmin,0) as efectivwidthmin,
isnull(cz.efectivwidthmax,0) as efectivwidthmax,
isnull(cz.koafporistmin,0) as koafporistmin, 
isnull(cz.koafporistmax,0) as koafporistmax,
CASE cz.__$operation 
WHEN 1 THEN 'DELETE'
WHEN 2 THEN 'INSERT'
WHEN 3 THEN 'Before UPDATE'
WHEN 4 THEN 'After UPDATE'
END operation,
map.tran_begin_time as beginT, 
map.tran_end_time as endT
FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh(sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all') AS cz 
INNER JOIN  [cdc].[lsn_time_mapping] map
    ON cz.[__$start_lsn] = map.start_lsn
)
SELECT  field, val, operation, beginT, endT FROM History
unpivot ( [val] for field in
(
--category,
area, 
oilwidthmin, 
oilwidthmax, 
efectivwidthmin, 
efectivwidthmax, 
koafporistmin, 
koafporistmax))t    where id = '2D166098-7CBD-4622-9EB0-000070506FE6'
```

Result of the query is following:
[image]

But previous result contains extra data.
Expected result must be following:
[image]

I know that the CDC tracks changes by rows. Or maybe i'm wrong? If no, how can i doing some comparer for `val` field in SQL. I have not deep knowledge in t-sql, and everything that comes to my mind is somehow used by cursors. Any ideas?
Maybe somehow use CT (change tracking)? Maybe somehow using `group by`?

Almost correct answer. Folowing query return expected result:

```
WITH History AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE cz.__$operation 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'DELETE'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'INSERT'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Before UPDATE'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'After UPDATE'
            END operation,
        map.tran_begin_time as beginT, 
        map.tran_end_time as endT
    FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh(sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all') AS cz 
        INNER JOIN  [cdc].[lsn_time_mapping] map
            ON cz.[__$start_lsn] = map.start_lsn
    where cz.GUID = '2D166098-7CBD-4622-9EB0-000070506FE6'
),
UnpivotedValues AS(
    SELECT  guid, field, val, operation, beginT, endT 
    FROM History
        UNPIVOT ( [val] FOR field IN
        (
            area, 
            oilwidthmin, 
            oilwidthmax, 
            efectivwidthmin, 
            efectivwidthmax, 
            koafporistmin, 
            koafporistmax
        ))t
),
UnpivotedWithLastValue AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        --Use LAG() to get the last value for the same field
        LAG(val, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY field ORDER BY BeginT) LastVal
    FROM UnpivotedValues
)
--Filter out record where the value equals the last value for the same field
SELECT * FROM UnpivotedWithLastValue WHERE val <> LastVal OR LastVal IS NULL ORDER BY guid
```

Result of this query looks like this:
[image]

But when `WHERE cz.GUID =` is absent or if query using several GUIDs in `WHERE` predicate i get folowing result:

[image]
This result for two GUIDs. Value for `LastVal` in first row must be 16691. Like `val` from row 4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set up CDC to only track values for the columns that have changed. However, you can quite easily filter out the unchanged values in your query.

Consider the following query, which is a simplified copy of your original query:

```
WITH History AS (
    SELECT
        *,
        CASE cz.__$operation 
            WHEN 1 THEN 'DELETE'
            WHEN 2 THEN 'INSERT'
            WHEN 3 THEN 'Before UPDATE'
            WHEN 4 THEN 'After UPDATE'
            END operation,
        map.tran_begin_time as beginT, 
        map.tran_end_time as endT
    FROM cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_Dbo_YourTable(sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('Dbo_YourTable'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all') AS cz 
        INNER JOIN  [cdc].[lsn_time_mapping] map
            ON cz.[__$start_lsn] = map.start_lsn
),
UnpivotedValues AS(
    SELECT id, field, val, operation, beginT, endT, t.tran_id
    FROM History
        UNPIVOT ( [val] FOR field IN
        (Column1, Column2, Column3))t
),
UnpivotedWithLastValue AS (
    SELECT 
        *,
        --Use LAG() to get the last value for the same field
        LAG(val, 1) OVER (PARTITION BY id, field ORDER BY BeginT) LastVal
    FROM UnpivotedValues
)
--Filter out record where the value equals the last value for the same field
SELECT * FROM UnpivotedWithLastValue WHERE val <> LastVal OR LastVal IS NULL
ORDER BY Id, beginT
```

In this query I have used the LAG() function to get the last value for each field. Based on this value you can filter out the unchanged records in your final query, and shown above.

Comment: Your example works fine if in `WITH History AS (` using `where cz.id = 'some ID'`. In this case, result in `LastVal` сorrespond to real values. But if `where` contains several id or `where` is absent then values for `LastVal` are mixed.

Comment: What are you using your cz.id column for? This is hard to answer without a data sample.

Comment: I'm sorry. Please look. I supplemented my questuon.

Comment: Aha - I see. I had simplified my query a bit too much :-) I've added an id column to the example now. You should add your cz.id in the PARTITION BY clause in the LAG() statement. Let me know if this doesn't solve the issue.

Comment: Yes! Now it is works perfect! Thank you very much. I have another question but it not not quite linked to this issue. If briefly. In this question i asked about one table but in real them mutch more. Al of them i want union in one result. The difference in the queries will be only in what I list in `UNPIVOT` section and in `FROM`. Can i create function with two arguments? If looks at this question then it result of `cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh` and list of fields in `PIVOT`.

Comment: Great!
Regarding your additional question: If I understand you correctly, then yes, it would be possible to create a stored procedure that outputs the changes from multiple tables. It may require a bit of dynamic SQL, and it may become a bit more complex, depending on your exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, you can use the ROW_NUMBER function to sequentially number the changes - after this, you can join each sequential change with the previous one (based on field and id) and output only the rows with the diffent value.

Something like this:

```
WITH 
History AS 
(
SELECT
    cz.GUID as Id, 
    cz.category,
    isnull(cz.area, 0) as area, 
    isnull(cz.oilwidthmin,0) as oilwidthmin, 
    isnull(cz.oilwidthmax,0) as oilwidthmax, 
    isnull(cz.efectivwidthmin,0) as efectivwidthmin,
    isnull(cz.efectivwidthmax,0) as efectivwidthmax,
    isnull(cz.koafporistmin,0) as koafporistmin, 
    isnull(cz.koafporistmax,0) as koafporistmax,
    CASE 
        cz.__$operation 
        WHEN 1 THEN 'DELETE'
        WHEN 2 THEN 'INSERT'
        WHEN 3 THEN 'Before UPDATE'
        WHEN 4 THEN 'After UPDATE'
    END operation,
    map.tran_begin_time as beginT, 
    map.tran_end_time as endT,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cz.GUID ORDER BY map.tran_end_time ASC) as rn
FROM 
    cdc.fn_cdc_get_all_changes_dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh(sys.fn_cdc_get_min_lsn('dbo_EXT_GeolObject_KategZalezh'), sys.fn_cdc_get_max_lsn(), 'all') AS cz 
INNER JOIN  
    [cdc].[lsn_time_mapping] map ON cz.[__$start_lsn] = map.start_lsn
),

History2 AS
(
    SELECT  id, field, val, operation, beginT, endT, rn FROM History
    unpivot ( [val] for field in
    (
    --category,
    area, 
    oilwidthmin, 
    oilwidthmax, 
    efectivwidthmin, 
    efectivwidthmax, 
    koafporistmin, 
    koafporistmax))t    
    where id = '2D166098-7CBD-4622-9EB0-000070506FE6'
)

-- return the values that were inserted first
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    History2 a
WHERE 
    a.rn=1

UNION ALL

-- ... and then return only the values that are different from the previous ones
SELECT
    a.*
FROM
    History2 a
INNER JOIN
    History2 b ON a.id = b.id AND a.field=b.field AND a.rn = b.rn-1 AND a.value<>b.value
WHERE
    a.rn>1
```

BTW; You could also configure CDC to track changes only in certain columns, not in the entire table. Look at the @captured_column_list of the sys.sp_cdc_enable_table stored procedure.

Comment: As I understand, I must create two temporary table and union them by filter `a.id = b.id AND a.field=b.field AND a.rn = b.rn-1 AND a.value<>b.value`. Am I right?

Comment: You don't need to create any temporary tables; you simply refer twice to the CTE (History2). Take a look at the suggested query.

Comment: Your example return several errors: `Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'.` and `Incorrect syntax near ','` Also i don't undestand query in History2. As i know `unpivot` applied to result table but in History 2 no any tables.

Comment: didn't test the query as i don't have a sample of your tables... i've now corrected the error; try to execute the changed query. the History2 CTE is simply the copy of your original query with some added columns (id, rn).

Comment: Thank you. Query is works but not properly. I update one field 2 times and another field 1 times. Query don't return last results for last updates but show last `endT`....